# Jetty and Dropwizard: KeyStores with multiple certificates are not supported on the base class org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory

Tags: java, maven, jetty, dropwizard, embedded-jetty

I am running into the follow error while upgrading my versions of Jetty for a Dropwizard project:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: KeyStores with multiple certificates are not supported on the base class org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory. (Use org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory$Server or org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory$Client instead)
```

The tricky part is that I do not directly set up my SslContextFactory in code. Instead, Dropwizard sets it up behind the scenes at application startup, where it quickly runs into this issue and fails.

I see from the [Dropwizard documentation](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/configuration.html) that certain environment variables can be set on the Jetty server that it spins up, but I do not see documentation on how to modify specific classes.

If I add a jetty.xml file within $JETTY_HOME$/etc/config, will Dropwizard know how to pick this up?

I just need to understand how Dropwizard picks up settings on Jetty so I can use SslContextFactory.Server and resolve this error at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of Dropwizard is too old.

Dropwizard properly uses the `SslContextFactory.Server` where appropriate.

Comment: We are using 1.3.29. Can you point to what version of Dropwizard pulls in `SslContextFactory.Server` correctly? @joakim-erdfelt

Comment: [Dropwizard 1.x was declared End of Life back in Dec 2020](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/3338) - Use any recent release of any supported major version of Dropwizard.